# Eclipse Pydev: mysterious error every time running Pydev console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

since recently I have not been able to use Pydev's console to run my codes and nor the Python interpreter within Eclipse.Every time I attempt to run code via Pydev's console or Python Interpreter calling from Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3032, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-e02eb4392d8d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:\\Users\\Novin Pendar\\Desktop\\Projects\\learning\\decorators.py')
NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined
```

**I'm using Eclipse Kepler 32-bit, Windows 64-bit, Python 2.7 and PyDev 3.3.3**

What do I do to fix this error? I'm really frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a bug from PyDev 3.3.3 (fixed quite some time ago already). If you upgrade to the latest version (4.4.0), it should be working!

Comment: I removed and reinstalled eclipse with the PyDev 3.3 and everything works now.